# How to Change label on Default page when user controls returns to page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a web user control. After the code of user control is returned to the default page, then I want to retrieve some value of  user control. 
 Like the following code...

```
<asp:Label ID="lblmaster" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<uc1:UserControl ID="WebUser" runat="server">
</uc1:UserControl>
```

The Label is visible only when the all the operations in user control are done. how this is possible??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax Extension controls - `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress`. Place the Label into UpdateProgress and `UserControl` in UpdatePanel. For more info read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx) article .

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Session to store the details when moving from usercontrol to usercontrol